# Posting many AJAX requests from one page -- how to send all necessary data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html-table, request

I'm building a page with a long table of entries which all include a "Yes" and "No" button in one column, and a dropdown box in another. Each row has an id that corresponds to a field in my database on my server.

I'm having trouble coming up with a good way to send all the data. What I need to be sent is the id, whether the "Yes" or "No" button was pushed, and the value in the dropdown menu if the "Yes" button was clicked.

I'm kind of new to this jQuery stuff so please don't expect me to know things out of context! Here's a sample row of the table:

```
<table id="check_table">
    <tr id="1234">
        <td><a href=".,.">fdsa</a><td>
        <td class="buttons"><button type="button" value="yes">Yes</button><button type="button" value="no">No</button></td>
        <td class="dropdown"><select name="problem_type">
            <option value="Thing 1">Thing1</option>
            <option value="Thing 2">Thing2</option>
            <option value="Thing 3">Thing3</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>

    ... More rows
</table>
```

Also, on the server-side, I'm using PHP to handle requests and connect to the database. All I want to know here is how I translate the data in the AJAX request to variables in PHP.

Comment: Are you wanting to post each row independently, or are you wanting to post all the table rows at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You have stumbled on encoding types. No matter what, you are going to recieve your form elements using `$_POST`. The format you recieve them is totally up to you.

You could recieve each form input as indevidual `$_POST` paramaters or the entire form as a single object using JSON.

```
//pagePostedToo.php
$thing1 = $_POST['thing1']; //im a string!
$thing2 = $_POST['thing2']; //im a string!

//pagePostedToo.php
$things = json_decode($_POST['things']); //im an array of things!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var btnValue = $(this).attr('value');
    var optionValue = $('select[name="problem_type"]').val();

    $.post({'php_script.php',{
        btnValue: btnValue,     //phpVariable: jsVariable
        optionValue: optionValue 
    }, function(data){
        // perform needed action with reply from php script
    });
});
```

and in php script you will catch thoose with

```
$button = $_POST['btnValue'];
$option = $_POST['optionValue'];
```